Method of image charges for ungrounded conductive sphere seems to have charge of $q$ and not $(r/a) q$?
Using the 2d scenario for simplification
Vector field of a point charge $q=1$ at (-4.1,0):
$$\vec F_1\left( {x,y} \right) = \left(\frac{x+4.1} {{\sqrt{(x+4.1)^2 + (y-0)^2}}^2}\right) \vec e_x + \left(\frac{y-0} {{\sqrt{(x+4.1)^2 + (y-0)^2}} ^2} \right) \vec e_y\\ = \frac{x+4.1} {(x+4.1)^2 + (y+0)^2}  \vec e_x + \frac{y} {(x+4.1)^2 + y^2} \vec e_y\\ $$


My model of the vector field of the induced charge on the sphere using a circle (radius 9.5, centre (5.5,0)):
$$\vec F_2\left( {x,y} \right) = \frac{2}{|C|}\sum_{(x_i, y_i) \in C} \left((x_i-5.5, y_i).\vec F_1(x_i,y_i)\right)\left(\frac{x-x_i} {(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2} \vec e_x + \frac{y-y_i} {(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i) ^2} \vec e_y \right) $$

(C is a set of 10000 equally spaced points on the circle (divide circumference by 10000 and increment angle by arc length / r). The constant 2 comes from the fact I didn't normalise the radius vector. If I did then it would be d (d was the magic constant to get it to work).)

The combined field, showing zero field within the sphere, because it cancels out.
$$\vec F_3\left( {x,y} \right) = \vec F_1\left( {x,y} \right) + \vec F_2\left( {x,y} \right)$$




Now I use the established model of two charges, with q'=(r/a) q, one at the centre of the sphere and one distanced (r^2)/a away:
$$\vec F_4 \left( {x,y} \right) = \frac{r}{a} \left( \frac{x-\left(5.5-\left(\frac{r^2}{a}\right)\right)} {\left(x-\left(5.5-\left(\frac{r^2}{a}\right)\right)\right)^2 +y^2} \vec e_x + \frac{y} {\left(x-\left(5.5-\left(\frac{r^2}{a}\right)\right)\right)^2 +y^2} \vec e_y \right) + 
 \frac{r}{a}\left(\frac{x-5.5} {(x-5.5)^2+y^2} \vec e_x + \frac{y} {(x-5.5)^2+y^2}\vec e_y\right) $$


The field difference between the two models outside the sphere should be zero, given that the established model is supposed to be giving the field outside the sphere, and the model I came up with gives the field inside and outside of the sphere
$$\vec F_5\left( {x,y} \right) = \vec F_4\left( {x,y} \right) - \vec F_2\left( {x,y} \right)$$

There is still a field

Most interestingly
$$\vec F_6\left( {x,y} \right) = \frac{a}{r} \vec F_4\left( {x,y} \right) - \vec F_2\left( {x,y} \right)$$

Which implies that the model $q'=(r/a) q$
is incorrect and it is in fact $q'=q$.

(small note: diagram keys should say range 0 to 0.1 not 0 to 1)

This needs a lot of clarification.

The answer is that the equation does not apply to 2D but to a 3D real-world scenario.
When using the 3D equations for the vector field of a point charge:
3D equivalent of $\vec{F_2}$:

3D equivalent of $\vec{F_4}$:

3D equivalent of $\vec{F_5}$:

When we compare the difference in the field strength along the x axis of
$\vec{F_2}$ and  $\vec{F_4}$

We can see there is still a small artifactual field remaining perhaps due to sphere not being fully uniform due to the Thompson problem. A fibonnaci sphere is 1500x more uniform than the built in SpherePoints (field is 1500x less inside an isolated charged sphere), but in this case where there is an external field across it, it only reduces the  field artifact by around 10x.
